# What is the UI Response Time Limit in Android?

Tags: android

i new in android developer, i want to know the UI response time limit in android, if any one know then please tell me.

Thanks you.

Comment: What do you mean by "UI response time limit"?

Comment: If you mean the time it takes before I give up and uninstall the app, the answer is < 1s.

Comment: what you actually want to know please clearify

Answer (score 7):

According to the reference page (http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-anr.html), it's **5 seconds** before getting an ANR (Application Not Responding)

Answer (score 1):

If by response time limit, you mean, the maximum amount of time before the Android OS determines an application as not running, then: 5 seconds!

Answer (score 1):

According to android developer forum:-

```
 - No response to an input event (such as key press or screen touch
   events) within 5 seconds.

 - A BroadcastReceiver hasn't finished executing within 10 seconds
```

Generally it happened when our application performing long running task in UI thread then android OS showing below popup :-

[image]

https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/vitals/anr.html

https://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-anr.html